# C# LINQ for converting List to Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have this class structure.  I want to convert list of device to dictionary which has key(from Tests class) to value (list of device).

```
class Device
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public ArrayList Tests;
}

class Tests
{
    public string[] Test { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, List<Device>> testToDeviceMapping = new Dictionary<string, List<Device>>();
foreach (Device device in devices)
{
    foreach (Tests test in device.Tests)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Test.Length; i++)
        {
            List<Device> deviceList = null;
            if (!testToDeviceMapping.ContainsKey(test.Test[i]))
            {
                deviceList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Device>();
            }
            else
            {
                deviceList = testToDeviceMapping[test.Test[i]];
            }
            deviceList.Add(device);
            testToDeviceMapping[test.Test[i]] = deviceList;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, but the last part should be list of Device.

```
Dictionary<string, List<Device>> testToDeviceMapping = devices.device.ToDictionary(d => d.Tests.ToArray().ToDictionary(t => t.ToString, d));
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use List<T> for your Tests type in Device so you can have static types and avoid boxing.

Comment: Given 3 devices that each have 2 tests in their Tests property, you want the final dictionary to have keys composed of unique strings that are the Test values, and each key has a value of the devices that contain that Test?

Comment: that's correct. For example, ['Test1, ['Device1', 'Device2']],  ['Test2, ['Device2', 'Device3'], ['Test3, ['Device1', 'Device3']];

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in some complex nested select like this:

```
  var devices = new List<Device>
{
    new Device
    {
        id = "1",
        name = "device1",
        Tests = new List<Tests>
        {
            new Tests {Test = new[] {"test1", "test2"}}
        }
    },
    new Device
    {
        id = "2",
        name = "device2",
        Tests = new List<Tests>
        {
            new Tests {Test = new[] {"test1", "test3"}}
        }
    },

};

var dictionary = devices.SelectMany(x => x.Tests.Select(z => new {Tests = z.Test, Device = x}))
                .SelectMany(x => x.Tests.Select(z => new {Test = z, x.Device}))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Test)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, z => z.Select(t => t.Device).ToList());
```